# Shopify : How to test webhooks in php

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I am new in shopify. I have created one app in php for shopify. I have registered webhooks using admin apis. But i don't know how to test webhooks. I have spent lots of time to figure out but not getting any proper response. How to get response and write stuff over there?

Is it like Apis? How to notify that webhooks are called or not.

Please help me.

Comment: which code you have tried for webhook? got any error?

Comment: I have not get any error. i want to test webhooks

Comment: Have you consulted their documentation? https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks#testing-webhooks

Answer (score 4):

Unlike APIs, Webhook is event driven(triggered on any event e.g. Order Creation) and send data in JSON/XML format to particular URL.

You can create a Webhook in your Shopify store by following steps.

1. Go to Settings -> Notification -> Webhooks -> Create Webhook
2. Select Event on which your webhook will be triggered data Format and URL(https) to which you want to send your data.

Now your data is available in JSON format to server location you have shared in URL field. You can use following code.

```
<?php

define('SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET', 'my_shared_secret');
function verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header){
  $calculated_hmac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, SHOPIFY_APP_SECRET, true));
  return hash_equals($hmac_header, $calculated_hmac);
}

$hmac_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_HMAC_SHA256'];
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$verified = verify_webhook($data, $hmac_header);
error_log('Webhook verified: '.var_export($verified, true)); //check error.log to see the result

?>
```

Comment: Hi @Deepak, i have the same problem and i used your code, i have this in an heroku app as i don't have a server. i am not receiving any data nor errors.

Can you please let me know if i need to change something on your code?

I tried to change the 'my_shared_secret' with my actual shared_secret and yea error

Comment: @NoobDev Free tier Heroku apps go to sleep by default, are you sure it's been woken up when the webhook is sent?