# How to receive a Webhook with JS / JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, webhooks

I want to receive a Webhook Post in JS/JQUERY (JSON format) from Shopify when a customer succesfully purchases a product. How do I setup a "listener"? A specific URL which is able to handle the received data?

I work with a One.com Domain Hosting Server.

The end result should be that I pick some parts of information of the JSON out and trigger a API Post which makes the proccessing of the order possible (which I already managed to work with).

I only don't know how to receive and temporarily save the data (and I researched a lot, but maybe with the wrong "keywords").

(sorry for the horrible english)

Comment: A webhook like this needs to use server side logic, not client side JS/jQuery

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what steps would you recommend now? which programming language is server based and "simple" to learn / work with?

Comment: See [Creating an Endpoint for Webooks](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks#creating-an-endpoint-for-webhooks). That page has code examples for Ruby, PHP, and Python. I'd choose PHP, but that's just my preference.

Comment: Also reference [Shopify : How to test webhooks in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472375/shopify-how-to-test-webhooks-in-php).